# Packagist / Composer Submit package on alternative port

Tags: package, composer-php, packagist

i would like to know if it s possible to add a package to packagist on a non default port 22. What if we have a GIT repo running on different port?

Thx for your help!

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. Did you try adding the repo URL? Note however that all the packages hosted on Github do use HTTPS as the published URL, probably because HTTP access through proxies is all you can depend on. SSH access might be unavailable to some.

Comment: Ouh ok so only on Gihub hosted projects are usable here? It´s not possible to add a repo provided by stash for example?

Comment: If it is publicly accessible, it can be added. But I think you should provide a HTTP based URL, which Stash also allows.